# How to convert white background pixels into black in an image using OpenCV, Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I have some cropped images and i also applied otsu thresholding on it. Now, i want to convert white pixels that are in the background into black pixels

[image: 1]

Need solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: complement your image by subtracting it from an array which all items are 255.

Comment: When you say you want to convert white pixels that are in the background into black pixels, do you mean 1) that you want to invert the colors and turn all white pixels to black pixels and vice versa, or do you mean 2) that you want *only* the white pixels which are part of the background to turn into black pixels?

Comment: Yes the 2nd one, I want to turn only those white pixels that are part of the background into black pixels.